# Issue while using Android Contact API

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

Problem while using Android Contact API

A Button is placed beside the EditText . When the user clicks on the Button , Contact API is called using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.PICK_CONTACT);
```

The above code will call the following method:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
            if (reqCode == Constants.PICK_CONTACT) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    String contactStr = getContactInfo(data);
                    mEditTxtTo.setText(contactStr);
                }
             }
}


protected String getContactInfo(Intent intent) {
        String contactEmail = "";
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            // Find Email Addresses
            Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);

            while (emails.moveToNext()) {
                if (contactEmail.trim().length() > 0) {
                    contactEmail = new StringBuilder(contactEmail).append(IShipdocsMobileConstants.SEMICOLON_DELIMITER)
                            .append(emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA))).toString();
                } else {
                    contactEmail = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                }
            emails.close();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return contactEmail;
    }
```

I have the added if - else condition to handle the following issue:

Suppose in contact named A , there are 3 email Id s . So , after the first email is added to contactEmail , the next email is appended after the first email separated by a semi-colon & the loop continues till the last element.

```
if (contactEmail.trim().length() > 0) {
                        contactEmail = new StringBuilder(contactEmail).append(";")
                                .append(emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA))).toString();
                    } else {
                        contactEmail = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

                }
```

The issue currently facing when mulitple email(s) are there for a single contact.

Suppose 3 contacts are there , A , B & C

Now , contact name : A  has the following email(s) :

a@a.com
b@b.com
c@c.com

Contact name : B has the following email(s):

b@b.com
c@c.com

If only contact A is added , 
b@b.com is being added twice on the contactEmail .
It seems to me as if the above code searches b@b.com on all the contacts.

So , the final email which was returned was : a@a.com , b@b.com , c@c.com , b@b.com

Any suggestions / hints for finding the error on the above code.

Comment: I think the first step is to identify if you are getting all 4 emails back in your Cursor query. It will help you figure out if there is a problem with the string building loop, or with the cursor query. You can use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(Cursor cursor)` to spit out the entire Cursor returned from the query for email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see how many times the outer loop:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
```

is executing for contact A. For each iteration of that loop, print out contactId and contactEmail like this:

```
Log.d("debug for stack overflow", contactEmail + " : " + contactId);
```

This will help determine what is happening.

If you still need more help after this, post the results of what I just suggested.